# Bad visualization when adding a second table relation

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a problem with the visualization of a `Columnheader` when I add a second relationship to the `DataSet`.

The thing is that the column disappears the first time I open the window but (without closing the app) it will appear if I click on another tab and return to the one I'm having the problem.

I know the problem comes from the second relationship because when I comment this line it works perfectly:
`DataSetGenerico.Relations.Add(relation2);`

The first image shows what happens when opening the window for the first time, and the second image shows what happens when clicking on another tab and returning to the tab with the problem (without closing the app).[image: First Time]

[image: Second Time]

You can see on the first image that "Tipo de Local" is shown but with a very small width (is between "Dni Propietario" and "DNI propietario"), the second time is shown perfectly.

The `AutoSizeColumnsMode`  is with `DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells`, I have tried all other `DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode` possibilities with no luck. Also `DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error I have found the solution.

To solve this problem all that should be done is create all the wanted **relations** first, then add all the **DataGridViewComboBoxColumn** that you would need or want. If you create a **relation** after the creation of a **DataGridViewComboBoxColumn** you will face this problem even if the **relation** and the **DataGridViewComboBoxColumn** have nothing in common.